# Custom decorator in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator

How do I access the variables of the class in which the decorator is called?

```
@TestDecorator()
export class AppController {
    private testData: number  = 15;
}

export const TestDecorator = (options: ICrudConfig) => (target: Object) => {
  console.log(target.prototype.testData);
};
```

target.prototype.testData is undefined

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Typescript's class decorator doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#class-decorators) explain it. your class decorator allows you to extend and modify a constructor, you can't access and modify the class's prototype directly.

Try console logging your target to see what you can access ;)

My recommendation: try returning a class that extends your target.

Remember that the class decorator is evaluated before the class is instantiated so you'll be able to override methods and constants but you wont be able to access variables that will be instantiated later on in the execution.

```
export const TestDecorator = (options: ICrudConfig) => (target: Object) => {
  return class extends target { // returns a new class extending the decorated one;
    constructor {
      super();
      console.log(this.testData);
    }
  };
};
```